# Developing oculus application in Unity using mrtk,no display when streaming debugging

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, oculusquest

I am creating a VR application for Oculus Quest using Unity3D.And I am trying to speed up the process using MRTK,but when streaming debugging in Unity Editor,there is no diaplay.But when I build a package whether a PC package or an apk,it runs normally.What should I set up in my project?

Answer (score 0):

For Debug, you can use DebugWindow. With it, you can see the log on the hololens device.